# How to make Two processes to complete one task, and whose finish task first, terminate another one

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, posix

I am looking for a good way to create 2 equally child processes, which will complete 1 task - to sort separately, one from the other, an array with numbers data with different algorithms for example [Merge-Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-using-multi-threading/), and [QuickSort](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/NSF-3/e-Book/FUNDAMENTALS/TM-example-quicksort.html).

The first process, which completed the task, should terminate another one (and print result)

Also which will be the best way to transfer data to processes (Pipes?)

Also is there something I didn't take into account?

I should use system functions, Posix and Linux based code

```
int main() {
pid_t child_a, child_b;

int unsortedData[MAX] = getNumericDataFromFile(/*filename*/);

// Open two pipes for communication
// The descriptors will be available to both
// parent and child.
int in_fd[2];
int out_fd[2];

if (pipe(in_fd) == -1) { // For child's stdin
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe In Failed");
    return 1;
}
if (pipe(out_fd) == -1) { // For child's stdout
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Out Failed");
    return 1;
}

if ((child_a = fork()) < 0) { // create first child process
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork of first child process Failed");
    return 1;
}
if (child_a == 0) {
    /* Child A code, execute first algorithm */
    int sortedData[MAX] = firstChildProcess(/*unsortedData*/); 
    /* terminate other process properly if its firs ? */

} else {
    if ((child_b = fork()) < 0) { // create second child process
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork of second child process Failed");
        return 1;
    }
    if (child_b == 0) {
        /* Child B code, execute second algorithm */
        int sortedData[MAX] = ChildProcess(/*unsortedData*/)
        /* terminate other process properly if its first? */
    } else {

        parentCode(..);/* Parent Code */
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

> Input :  6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
>
> Output: Second algorithm finished first sorting task with result:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Thank you in advance

Comment: While I'm sure you will get some good answers, I'd like to point out that sometimes it's best to ask yourself `why?`. It's better to re-think the problems than to solve them exactly as stated. It's also best not to waste computing resources...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, I will try to re-think it. The idea behind that question is that I am trying to complete it, but I want to hear best practices and solutions in that case and to use them., not just to make it work :)

Comment: It would be much simpler if you can have the *parent* terminate the second process, since it knows both their PIDs; it can `wait()` for one to finish and then `kill()` the other one.  If you insist on having one child kill the other, then you need some IPC mechanism to communicate the PID of the second process to the first one, and you have a hard time avoiding a race condition in case PIDs get reused.